# ParsePush.SubscribeAsync() & SaveAsync() Keep throwing System.AggregateException all the time on Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, .net, windows, parse-platform, uwp

ParsePush.SubscribeAsync() & SaveAsync() Keep throwing System.AggregateException all the time on Windows 10 UWP. The framework doesn't even register the device.
Here the stack trace:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Parse.PlatformHooks.get_AppName()
   at Parse.ParseInstallation.SaveAsync(Task toAwait, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Parse.ParseObject.<>c__DisplayClass41.<SaveAsync>b__40(Task toAwait)
   at Parse.Internal.TaskQueue.Enqueue[T](Func`2 taskStart, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Parse.ParseObject.SaveAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Parse.ParseObject.SaveAsync()
   at MyApp.MainPage.<Page_Loaded>d__1.MoveNext()
```

I cannot get it working and I didn't see similar cases!
**Note that I'm using Parse from NuGet**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in pull request #91 It was caused by by AppName getter, trying to access AppManifest using an old Xml schema.